# Восстановить синусоиды

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Хочу попробовать восстановить оригинальные значения синусоиды из существующей, которая изображена на втором графике рисунка. У меня получилось сделать её из двух других `y` (первый график рисунка).
Как слить их и превратить в новую понятно, а вот как существующую разбить на волны - нет. Т.к. мы не знаем изначально сколько синусоид содержится в той, которую хотим преобразовать, то видимо должны задать на сколько именно будем разбивать её. Но как это сделать, может у кого-то есть опыт работы с такими задачами.

```
# код простой одной синусоиды

x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
y = np.sin(x*10)
plt.plot(y)
```

[Вот тут выложил данные над которыми хотим сделать преобразование](https://dropmefiles.com/0o5fR)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Знать количество исходных синусоид совсем необязательно, и в общем случае даже невозможно.  Гуглите преобразования Фурье.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Для вычисления конкретных значений амплитуд и фаз нужно делать преобразование Фурье. А потом вручную его анализировать. К сожалению, автоматизировать этот процесс совсем непросто. Причина в том, что если длина отрезка не кратна периоду, то вместо острого пика дельта-функции в частотном представлении наблюдаеся нечто вроде юбки. Или, как принято называть, "лепесток".

Вот пример - простая сумма трёх синусоид c разными фазами

```
x = np.linspace(-20,20,4000)
y = np.sin(x) + 0.5*np.cos(2*x) + 0.3*np.cos(3*x-0.25*np.pi)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выглядит дискретный спектр этого сигнала?

```
fft_data = np.fft.rfft(y)
fft_freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(y), d=(max(x)-min(x))/len(x))
fft_amps = np.abs(fft_data) # амплитуды, увеличенные в 2000 раз
plt.plot(fft_freqs[:25], fft_amps[:25], 'o')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите, какая "юбка" вокруг самой левой частоты? Если задачу решать в лоб, то в реконструированном выражении будет несколько десятков синусоид.

Хуже того, нельзя просто взять и задать маску по порогу, такую как `fft_amp>500` - в маску попадут не только несущие частоты, но и паразиты из юбки левой частоты.

Нужно выковыривать частоты вручную, догадываясь о том, какой результат хотим получить.

```
def window(freqs, left, right):
    result = np.zeros(freqs.shape)
    result[np.logical_and(left<=freqs, freqs<=right)] = 1.0
    return result

# вырезаем диапазоны частот, глядя на дискретный спектр
ind1 = np.argmax(fft_amps*window(fft_freqs, 0, 0.2))
ind2 = np.argmax(fft_amps*window(fft_freqs, 0.25, 0.4))
ind3 = np.argmax(fft_amps*window(fft_freqs, 0.4, 0.6))

inds=[ind1, ind2, ind3]
```

При таком ручном анализе получаем

- частоты: `fft_freqs[inds]*2*np.pi` => `[0.9424778 , 2.04203522, 2.98451302]`
- амплитуды: `fft_amps[inds]*2/len(x)` => `[0.76783882, 0.44836175, 0.33007853]`
- фазы в нуле: `(np.angle(fft_data[inds]) - min(x)*fft_freqs[inds]*2*np.pi)/np.pi%2` => `[1.51029717, 1.95922772, 1.74223384]`

Фаза в данном случае это аргумент `cos(n*x + phase)`
`rfft` вычисляет фазу в начале интервала. Так как в нашем примере интервал начинается в `-20`, то нужно к фазе прибавить число периодов, укладывающихся в отрезок длиной `20`.

То есть вместо `sin(x)+0.5*cos(2x) + 0.3cos(3*x-pi/4)` мы получили что-то вроде `0.77*sin(x) + 0.45*cos(2x) + 0.33cos(3x-pi/4)`

Видно, что фазы и частоты худо бедно угадали, но во всех случаях неверно посчитаны амплитуды.

Что делать?

Рецепт один. Нужно подобрать длину интервала `x` таким образом, чтобы хотя бы у одной частоты исчез лепесток.

В моём примере нужно отбросить примерно 230 точек:

```
xx = x[:3770]
fft_data = np.fft.rfft(y[:len(xx)])
fft_freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(xx), d=(max(xx)-min(xx))/len(xx))

fft_amps = np.abs(fft_data)

plt.plot(fft_freqs[:25], fft_amps[:25], 'o')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите, лепестки практически исчезли. Можно считать частоты, амплитуды и фазы:

```
inds = fft_amps > 100
print(fft_amps[inds]*2/len(xx),\
      fft_freqs[inds]*2*np.pi, 
      (np.angle(fft_data[inds]) - min(xx)*fft_freqs[inds]*2*np.pi)/np.pi%2)
```

Амплитуды и частоты получились отлично: `[1.00041912 0.49972138 0.30016089]` и `[0.9999917  1.99998339 2.99997509]`.

С фазами чуть похуже: `[1.50153704 0.00301094 1.75444463]`, но лучше, чем в первом случае.

**UPDATE 2**

А если бы я отбросил не 230 точек, а 231, то результат получился бы ещё лучше:

- амплитуды `[1.00001288 0.49999182 0.30000524]`
- частоты `[1.00025709 2.00051418 3.00077126]`
- фазы `[1.50168492 0.00336792 1.75504976]`

Причинав том, что в этом случае длина интервала равна `12.0001 pi` , то есть с хорошей точностью кратна всем периодам из примера.

**Первое решение -- находит только несущие частоты**

Достаточно инструмента "периодограмма". Эта функция вернёт вам частотный спектр, из которого вам нужно отобрать две частоты с максимальными амплитудами.

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as signal

x = np.linspace(-20,20,4000)
y = np.sin(2*x) + np.sin(x*5)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Получится вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как разложить сигнал на гармоники:

```
freqs, spectrum = signal.periodogram(y, fs=len(x)/(max(x)-min(x)))
plt.plot(freqs, spectrum)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что у двух гармоник явно ненулевые амплитуды

```
freqs_inds = np.where(spectrum > 15)
factors= freqs[freqs_inds]*2*np.pi
print(factors)
```

Результат: `[2.04203522 5.02654825]`

Видно, что результаты совпадают с исходными синусоидами с хорошей точностью. Погрешность вызвана тем, что длина интервала не кратна периоду функции, поэтому разложение Фурье "не попало" в нужные частоты.

Comment: @Святостлав_и Ну понятно, что там вместо `inds` должно быть `freqs_inds`, я поправил

Comment: @Святостлав_и переделал ответ. Добавил анализ амплитуд и фаз.